# install ssis to my current MS sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, ssis

what is the proper way to install ssis to my current deverloper version 2008 r2. Do I have to uninstall my current one? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need to uninstall.

Select  Start > Microsoft SQL Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Installation Server

Then select Installation and ‘New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation’

From here you can start the addition of  the required features to your current installation.